# Is it possible to change the order of * and & in the arguments of a function?

Tags: c++

```
void ref_func(int *&ref1,int *&ref2){
        int *tmp = ref2;
        ref2 = ref1;
        ref1 = tmp;
}
int main(){
        int num1 = 5;
        int num2 = 29;
        int *ptr1 = &num1;
        int *ptr2 = &num2;
        ref_func(ptr1, ptr2);

        cout<< *ptr1<<endl;
        cout<< *ptr2<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to change the order of `*` and `&` in the parameters of a function?
Like this

```
void ref_func(int &*ref1,int &*ref2)
```

Comment: Yes, you can do `int&*` instead of `int*&`, but these are two different types. Try it out to see what happens.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Is `int&*` meaningful?

Comment: No, `int&*` is not meaningful or allowed in C++. A pointer cannot point to a reference type.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Those * and & are part of a type of the parameter. There is no such thing as pointer to reference in C++, and thus &* can never appear in a type.